# Como remover a tabela gerada automaticamente do gridview em asp: TemplateField?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, gridview

Como remover a tabela gerada automaticamente do gridview em asp: TemplateField?

Eu estou usando um gridview como este

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<ul>
<li><%#Eval("Nome") %></li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Mas quando eu executo e vejo o código fonte da página, é exibido esse resultado:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-
collapse:collapse;">

<tr>
<td>
<ul>
<li>Nome do usuario/li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

mais eu quero o resultado sejá assim:

```
<ul>
<li>Nome do usuario</li>
</ul>
```

lembrando que a linguagem que estou utilizando é VB.NET

Comment: Use o `repeater` então, além de ser mais leve o resultado é o que precisa

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema ao invés de usar uma GridView eu utilizei uma DataList com a propriedade `RepeatLayout="Flow"` dessa forma meu código ficou assim:

```
<asp:DataList ID="tabeladobanco" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
<ItemTemplate>
<li><%#Eval("Nome") %></li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Resultado do código fonte:

```
<ul>
<li>Nome do usuario</li>
</ul>
```